# Creating Brighter Color? (Java)

Tags: java

I was trying to create a brighter color using the default colors that `java.awt.Color` provides

but when I draw using the 2 colors, they appear to be the same?

```
Color blue = Color.BLUE;
Color brighterBlue = blue.brighter();

test.setColor(blue);
test.fillCircle(size);

test.setColor(brighterBlue);
test.drawCircle(size);
```

Comment: Is it possible that your blue was already the brightest blue?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you code would draw over itself, a color of R = 0, G = 0, B = 255, isn't likely to become much brighter blue than it already is...

Comment: @lugubrious&MadProgrammer: okay i went back and checked, the method works with creating a darker color so i guess it is the brightest? Thank you so much for the comment <3 

Ps: the overlap was because i wanted a circle with a border and i dont know any better ways >_<

Comment: @CJDKL The issue here is that "brightest" isn't a very well-defined term. The maths that `Color.brighter()` does actually increase the *value* of the color in the HSV space, which doesn't have a lot to do with how close to white it is, it just means it's the "bluest" blue there is. (The value axis of HSV is pretty much egregiously dumb.) HSL is better but still, a blue will seem darker than a yellow of the same saturation and lightness.

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of ways to approach this problem.

The most obvious way is to add a fraction to an existing color value, for example...

```
int red = 128;
float fraction = 0.25f; // brighten by 25%

red = red + (red * float);
```

Instead, you could apply a load factor to the color instead.  We know the maximum value for a color element is 255, so instead of trying to increasing the color factor itself, you could increase the color element by a factor of the over all color range, for example

```
int red = 128;
float fraction = 0.25f; // brighten by 25%

red = red + (255 * fraction); // 191.75
```

This basically increases the color element by a factor 255 instead...cheeky.  Now we also need to take into consideration the fact that the color should never be greater than 255

This will allow you to force colors to approach white as the brighten and black as the darken...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BrighterColor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BrighterColor();
    }

    public BrighterColor() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.fill(rec);
            g2d.translate(0, getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.setColor(brighten(Color.BLUE, 0.25));
            g2d.fill(rec);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make a color brighten.
     *
     * @param color Color to make brighten.
     * @param fraction Darkness fraction.
     * @return Lighter color.
     */
    public static Color brighten(Color color, double fraction) {

        int red = (int) Math.round(Math.min(255, color.getRed() + 255 * fraction));
        int green = (int) Math.round(Math.min(255, color.getGreen() + 255 * fraction));
        int blue = (int) Math.round(Math.min(255, color.getBlue() + 255 * fraction));

        int alpha = color.getAlpha();

        return new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);

    }

}
```

Comment: This approach skews the saturation a little as per HSL. Starting with `hsl(220, 75%, 27%)` (i.e. `#113377` to avoid clipping), adding 128 to lighten by 50% to each component ends up with `hsl(220, 86%, 77%)`. It does however adjust lightness correctly and leaves the hue untouched.

Comment: And turns out that if either colour clips, this skews the hue too. E.g. lightening `hsl(210, 33%, 40%)`, or `#446688`, ends up with `hsl(205, 100%, 88%)`. (The saturation is completely messed up at this point but less visible at the high lightness.)

Comment: I don't dispute that this is less then mathamatically perfect. I spent a lot of time looking about for algorithms that would produce the desired effect. For me, if I start at 0 and move towards 1, I can "see" the color shift towards white. I agree that generally, modifying the HSL is probably a more perfect solution, but the algorithms I saw using this method didn't produce quite the same result over my test range - but this is more about my needs at the time...

Comment: I'm not really aiming to knock at your solution - it's simple to understand, the difference isn't *that* dramatic and it might serve the OP's needs. I'm just pointing out it diverges from what working in the very very common HSL colour space would accomplish, which is designed to map 1:1 to RGB. (And is slightly perceptually better to my eyes, although if you were going for that you'd use CIELAB.)

Comment: You're points are valid and welcome ;) - I'm always interested in finding better understandings and ways of achieving things.  When I first started playing around with these algorithms, nothing I found could brighten black, except this approach.  If I was working with an application that was color based, I would certainly prefer to use HLS over RBG for this type of thing

Answer (score 6):

Quoting [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#brighter%28%29):

> This method applies an arbitrary scale factor to each of the three RGB components of this Color to create a brighter version of this Color.

So, assuming that `Color.blue` is the color `rgb(0, 0, 255)`, the brighter method would attempt to:

1. Multiply the `0`s by the scale factor, resulting in 0s again; and
2. Multiply the `255` by a scale factor, which because of capping results in `255` again.

Do note that the *hue-saturation-value* (where "value" is the same as "brightness") colour coordinate model is not the same as the *hue-saturation-**lightness*** model, which behaves somewhat more intuitively. (See Wikipedia on [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).) Unfortunately Java doesn't have HSL calculations built in, but you should be able to find those by searching easily.

Comment: You can check out [HSL Color](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/) for one implementation.

Comment: but.. the scale factor amounts to how much exactly?

Comment: @jj_ It doesn't matter for the purposes of this question. No matter what the scale factor is - as long as it's greater than `1`, which it always will be otherwise the method would darken the colour, not brighten it - it won't change a of the RGB components whose value is `0` or `255`.

Comment: @jj_ For what it's worth, Grepcode says it's the reciprocal of `0.7` = `7 / 10` ≈ `1.43` : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/awt/Color.java?av=f